# JFLAP Turing Machine shortcut issue

Tags: turing-machines, jflap

In [JFLAP](http://jflap.org), there are some shortcuts for Turing machine transitions. One of these shortcuts allows you to transition as long as the current tape symbol isn't the indicated symbol. For example, the transition !g,x;R basically says "Take this transition if the current tape symbol is not g".

So far, so good. But the transition I want is !□,~;R which basically says "Move right as long as the current symbol is not the end-of-string (empty cell) symbol". The problem is I cannot figure out how to type in "!□".

The [JFLAP online documentation](http://www.jflap.org/tutorial/turing/one/index.html#syntax) has this to say:

> The first shortcut is that there exists the option of using
>   the “!” character  to convey the meaning of “any character 
>   but this character.” For example, concerning the transition 
>   (!a; x, R), if the head encounters any character but an “a”, 
>   it will replace the character with an “x” and move right. 
>   To write the expression “!□”, just type a “1” in when inputting
>   a command.

How do I actually do what that last sentence is trying to explain to me?

Comment: I don't know anything about this software, but have you tried typing 1 like it says to?

Comment: Gosh...I actually thought of that :)
Since 1 is a valid tape symbol...I am stuck...

Comment: Thanks Zifre. The "when inputting a command" threw me because I hadn't seen that terminology before...I did a google search of the entire site for "inputting command" and got exactly that one reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I just realized the documentation has a typo. Where it says 'type a "1"', it should say "!". JFLAP sees the bare "!" and appends the "□". Thanks to Zifre...I tried harder.

Comment: Okay, that would make more sense. I was thinking, what if the symbol is 1? If it actually is a typo, you should report it to the developers so they can fix it.